# Magento2 - Wishlist counter is suddenly stopped working in the header

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I am using Ultimo theme in the site and few changes to the `My Wishlist` to `wishlist` and added one icon with link and also changed `1 item/items` to `1%` from csv only but suddenly counter stopped working and it doesn't show  in the header section.

Below is my code in **link.phtml** file :

```
<li class="link wishlist" data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">
 <span class="ic ic-heart icon-center"></span>
    <span data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'" class="link wishlist">
      <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist') ?>">
         <?php echo __('My Wishlist') ?>
         <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter --><span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span><!-- /ko -->
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you run deploy command , php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and remove var folder from root

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the cache only.It can work well with cache enabled.
Thanks

Comment: With cache disabled, the count was not working properly but after clear/flush cache it again started working again.Changes in the code are working fine.

Comment: yes, it is always work with cache enabled, because basically it's working with cookies and cache key to get this counter,this answer will sure help to others so +1